# A Builtin function to Convert Byte to String

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
    public static string ByteToString(byte[] Bytes, int Length)
    {
        Debug.Assert(Length <= Bytes.GetLength(0));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            str.Append((char) Bytes[i]);
        }

        return str.ToString();
    }
```

Is there a builtin function for this? `BitConverter.ToString()` doesn't yield the same output as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string myString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

there's also an overload that takes the index, and count.